# Access Tokens in OAuth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0

This question might be based on some assumptions or misunderstandings, but in most OAuth version 1 servers, it's possible for a user to generate an access token and an access token secret along with an access level setting.

In OAuth2 this has been replaced with refresh tokens instead, and this concept messes up my integration with another service provider.

Basically, what we would like to do is having this permanent access token, so the user doesn't have to log in twice (the second time to allow for access).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a permanent access token conflicts with the purpose of an access token in OAuth 2.0 though you may find some providers/implementations that allow for that.

What you should rather do is use the refresh token to get a new access token when the old one expires. This does not mean that the user would have to login again. The reason for the refresh token to exist is exactly to prevent the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a permanent refresh token.

In oAuth2 access token are designed to be short lived and refresh one to have a much longer life-time. In all case, user will have to login to grant the access during the authorization code phase.

see http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2013/03/10/understanding-oauth2/

Answer (score 1):

The OAuth2 process is as follows:

When users log into an application, they will receive an access token and a Refresh token that will be stored in the client side. In the server side, the Refresh token has to be stored in DB and will have long expiration (example: 1 month). A user can get a new access token (when it expires, every 30 minutes for example) using a refresh token (grant_type=refresh_token), that the user had received in the first request for token.

When an access token expires, the client must send a refresh token.

For example:

```
refresh_token=74dc51c2d6f841a4aaef6ef6d4075c0d&grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=webApp
```

If this refresh token exists in DB, the server will return to the client a new access token, without requiring user's username/password.